# Android how to use animation after an animator

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help me with my code? What i'm trying to do is when imageView get touched it will run animator and move the view to the center of the screen. After the animator finish the imageView will set another onTouch to run an animation for scaling from 0.0 - 1.0.But the animation will not start from the new position of the view but instead it start from the previous position of the view.

```
private void animation() {
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            imageView.animate().translationY(height/2).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0,1,0,1);
                            scale.setDuration(1000);
                            imageView.startAnimation(scale);
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The link is what i got from the code
http://sendvid.com/0vbtkhi7

and the link below is the result i want to get by using animation

http://sendvid.com/68q53bh6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah i found the solution basically i just need to update the pivot.

```
private void animation() {
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            imageView.animate().translationY(height/2).setDuration(1000).start();
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1,imageView.getWidth()/2,imageView.getY() + imageView.getHeight()/2);
                    scaleAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                    imageView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

btw thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using ViewAnimation. It is only animates the View but not the object itself thus object coordinates remain and when you reload new animation it starts with unchanged X and Y.
You should use the [Android Property Animation API.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

It is more simple and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: from the docs: `ViewPropertyAnimator View#animate()` "This method returns a ViewPropertyAnimator object, which can be used to animate specific properties on this View."

Comment: But i though animator is something like a move view animation? So when animator end at a point, that point is where the view at? Even i'm using ObjectAnimator is still the same result.